# Inequalities with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

For a linear system of equations constrained by inequalities, is $ Ax \le b => y^TAx \le y^Tb $ acceptable? Or does that not generally hold.

($ y^T $ being the transpose of $y$).

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? Do you mean: $Ax\leq b$ is equivalent to $y^TAx \le y^Tb$, or $Ax\leq b$ implies $y^TAx \le y^Tb$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'implies'. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are column vectors, *and that the entries of* $\mathbf y$ *are non-negative*, then yes, $A\mathbf x \leq b$ implies $\mathbf y^TA\mathbf x \leq \mathbf y^Tb$.

This amounts to taking a linear combination of inequalities where the weights are non-negative. Incidentally, this can be used to prove the "Weak Duality Theorem", *i.e.*, that the value of the objective function of a maximization problem is bounded above by the value of the corresponding objective function of the dual minimization problem.